# How to convert time zone id to to time zone name in js or moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

How to convert time zone id to to time zone name by `moment-timezone.js`

Example:

```js
const timeZone = moment.tz('America/Mexico_City');
timeZone.zoneAbbr() // CST to Central Standard Time
timeZone.format('z') // CST to Central Standard Time
```

I need to have `Central Standard Time`

Comment: Getting null for `const timeZone = moment.tz.zone('America/Mexico_City');
console.log(timeZone)`

Comment: MomentJS is dead btw, as browsers' support for dates and times is now much better: https://8thlight.com/blog/justyna-jurkowska/2021/06/16/life-after-moment.html (kinda like how jQuery is dead now that `querySelector` works and IE is gone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are considering using plain ole JavaScript as an alternative, simply use the [Intl.DateTimeFormat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) to control any aspect of a date or time display.

Like this:

```js
const time = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en" , {timeZoneName: "long"});
let date = new Date();
console.log(time.format(date));
```

Comment: Upvoted because we really don't need to include MomentJS' huge **386.02 KB** _bundled_ JS library in web-applications just for this.

Comment: I agree - the use of momentjs had its day - but that day is long past - and, the authors know this, acknowledge this and no longer support the library. That should be a central argument against the encouragement of [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Date.toLocaleTimeString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) to get the timezone name (either long or short style):

```js
function getTimeZoneName(timeZone, timeZoneName = 'short') {
    let [,...tz] = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en', { timeZoneName: "long", timeZone, timeZoneName, hour12: false }).split(' ');
    return tz.join(' '); 
}

let timeZones = ['America/Mexico_City', 'America/Los_Angeles', 'Europe/Berlin'];
for(let timeZone of timeZones) {
    console.log('\nTimezone:', timeZone);
    console.log('Long/Short name:', getTimeZoneName(timeZone, 'long'), '/', getTimeZoneName(timeZone, 'short'));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using moment, you need to override the `zoneName` function,  to use `zz` token.

Ref - https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/formatting/

```js
const timeZone = moment().tz('America/Mexico_City');

var abbrs = {
    EST : 'Eastern Standard Time',
    EDT : 'Eastern Daylight Time',
    CST : 'Central Standard Time',
    CDT : 'Central Daylight Time',
    MST : 'Mountain Standard Time',
    MDT : 'Mountain Daylight Time',
    PST : 'Pacific Standard Time',
    PDT : 'Pacific Daylight Time',
};

moment.fn.zoneName = function () {
    var abbr = this.zoneAbbr();
    return abbrs[abbr] || abbr;
};

console.log(timeZone.format('zz'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```